# discord.py - Total messages not being counted accurately (if messages were sent too fast) (leveling system, JSON file)

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm making a leveling system for my bot. I found a bug with counting total messages, and I tried to fix that by adding by 1 for each message sent to each user. It works, but it doesn't count accurately. When I send messages too fast, instead of counting 4, it counts 3. I've tried placing the lines all over the place and found no fixes. Does anyone know how to make this more accurate? Please and thank you.

Focus:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        with open('leveldb.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        # Check if the user is in the cooldown dictionary
        if message.author.id in message_cooldown:
            current_time = time.time()
            last_message_time = message_cooldown[message.author.id]

            # Check if the user's cooldown has expired (0.5 seconds cooldown)
            if current_time - last_message_time < 1.5:
                if log_enabled == True:
                    with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        today = date.today()
                        f.write(f'\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {message.author.name} has sent a message within cooldown, therefore, no xp')
                if debug_mode == True:
                    print(f"Debug: Message sent too fast, not adding XP for user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
                return
        await update_data(users, message.author, message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.guild)
        await add_totalmsgsent(users, message.author, message.guild)
        if debug_mode == True:
            print(f"Debug: 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
            if log_enabled == True:
                with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                    t = time.localtime()
                    today = date.today()
                    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                    f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}.")
```

**FULL** code (for your needs):

```
message_cooldown = {}


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        with open('leveldb.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        # Check if the user is in the cooldown dictionary
        if message.author.id in message_cooldown:
            current_time = time.time()
            last_message_time = message_cooldown[message.author.id]

            # Check if the user's cooldown has expired (0.5 seconds cooldown)
            if current_time - last_message_time < 1.5:
                if log_enabled == True:
                    with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        today = date.today()
                        f.write(f'\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {message.author.name} has sent a message within cooldown, therefore, no xp')
                if debug_mode == True:
                    print(f"Debug: Message sent too fast, not adding XP for user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
                return
        await update_data(users, message.author, message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.guild)
        await add_totalmsgsent(users, message.author, message.guild)
        if debug_mode == True:
            print(f"Debug: 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
            if log_enabled == True:
                with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                    t = time.localtime()
                    today = date.today()
                    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                    f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}.")


        # Update the last message time for the user
        message_cooldown[message.author.id] = time.time()

        with open('leveldb.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['total_messages_sent'] = 0
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['total_messages_sent'] = 0
async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp
async def add_totalmsgsent(users, user, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['total_messages_sent'] += 1

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/3))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      embed = discord.Embed(title=f" Level up!", description="{} has leveled up to **Level {}!**".format(user.mention, lvl_end), color=discord.Colour.green())
      await channel.send(embed=embed)
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end
      if debug_mode == True:
        print(f"Debug: {user.name} has leveled up to  Level {lvl_end}!")
        if log_enabled == True:
            with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                t = time.localtime()
                today = date.today()
                current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {user.name} has leveled up to Level {lvl_end}!")

with open('leveldb.json', 'r') as f:
    levelfind = f.read()

@bot.tree.command(name='level', description='View your own level, or another members level.')
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
        if not member:
                # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
                with open('leveldb.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    users = json.load(f)
                lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['level']
                exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['experience']
                with open('leveldb.json', 'r') as file:
                    data = json.load(file)
                data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
                sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['experience'])
                current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['experience']
                current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['level']
                totalmessages = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['total_messages_sent']
                next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 3
                missing_exp = int(next_exp - current_exp)
                pos = enumerate(sorted_data)
                for pos, (id) in enumerate(sorted_data):
                    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {} '.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
                    embed.add_field(name="XP until Next Level", value=f"{missing_exp} XP")
                    embed.add_field(name="Total Messages Sent", value=f"{totalmessages} Messages", inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name="Place on leaderboard", value=f"#{pos+1}")
                    embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.user.name}", icon_url=ctx.user.avatar)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.user.avatar)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"Server: {ctx.guild.name}")
                await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
                if debug_mode == True:
                    print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
                if log_enabled == True:
                    with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        today = date.today()
                        f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
        else:
            # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
            with open('leveldb.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                users = json.load(file)
            lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
            exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
            current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
            current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
            totalmessages = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['total_messages_sent']
            messages_sent = int(exp // 4)
            next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 3
            missing_exp = int(next_exp - current_exp)

            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {} '.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.add_field(name="XP until Next Level", value=f"{missing_exp} XP")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar)
            embed.add_field(name="Total Messages Sent", value=f"{totalmessages} Messages", inline=False)
            embed.set_author(name=f"User: {member.name}\nServer: {ctx.guild.name}", url=ctx.user.avatar)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested User ID: {member.id} | Sender ID: {ctx.user.id} | Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}")
            if debug_mode == True:
                print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")
            if log_enabled == True:
                with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                    today = date.today()
                    t = time.localtime()
                    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                    f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")

            await ctx.response.send_message(embed = embed)


@bot.tree.command(name="leaderboard", description="View the servers leaderboard. (Levels)")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Leaderboard for {ctx.guild.name}", color = discord.Color.blurple())
    with open('leveldb.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
    sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)
    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data):
            member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
            if member is None:
                embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - This user has left the server. :(", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
                if pos+1 > 9:
                    break  
                continue # This skips the current member
            else:
                embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name} (@{member.name})", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
                embed.set_footer(text="Pro tip: Use /level [user] to view more specific information about that member")
                if pos+1 > 9:
                    break  
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    if debug_mode == True:
        print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {ctx.guild.name}'s leaderboard")
        if log_enabled == True:
            with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                today = date.today()
                t = time.localtime()
                current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} viewed a servers leaderboard")
```

JSON file example:

```
{
  "757383943116030074": {
    "123456789012345678": {
      "experience": 0,
      "level": 1,
      "total_messages_sent": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This check `if current_time - last_message_time < 1.5` ends with `return` which would not add to the total message count. So reasonably, if messages were being sent too fast, it would not increment the count.